# Why URL mapping for tomcat has to have application name inside?

Tags: tomcat

When I deploy an application named let's say `App` with a servlet `Servlet` with tomcat, then I can access it using URL `localhost:8080/App/Servlet`. Why not `localhost:8080/Servlet`? Can I configure it so that `/Servlet` redirects to `/App/Servlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deploy your web application with the special name `ROOT`.

That'll be either in `tomcat/webapps/ROOT` or `tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war` (unless you deploy in a different way). Note: If memory serves me right, then those have to be capital letters for ROOT, even on Windows

Another option is to bring the configuration into [Tomcat's context.xml](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html), in your web-application's `META-INF/context.xml` (see "path" in the docs)